# Yii2 codeception authentication and XML reports output

Tags: unit-testing, testing, yii2, codeception

I have some trouble testing my code with codeception in Yii2 and i hope one of you can help me.

1. First of all my authentication doesn't work as expected.
   In my Class **PagesUrl** the user isn't logged in but in my template file the user is logged in. Whenever the page is not accessed with Codeception it's working fine.
   Code to check if user is logged in: `var_dump(Yii::$app->getUser()->getIsGuest());`

Config of UrlManager:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
               [
                 'class' => 'common\routes\PagesUrl',
                 'pattern' => '',
                 'route' => 'site/index',
               ],
               //Some additional rules
             ],
        ]
```

2. Second I can't seem to generate XML reports.
   Command for test output: `codecept run functional LoginFormCest --xml -vvv`

Gives this output:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.0
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.35-1-g912b8c1e9 by Sebastian Bergmann and                       contributors.

Functional Tests (5) ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules: Filesystem, Yii2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Printing JUNIT report into report.xml


  [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception]
  Undefined index: log_incomplete_skipped


Exception trace:
 () at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\codeception\base\src\Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler.php:75
 Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler->errorHandler() at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\codeception\base\src\Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner.php:145
 Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->applyReporters() at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\codeception\base\src\Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner.php:91
 Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\codeception\base\src\Codeception\SuiteManager.php:157
 Codeception\SuiteManager->run() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:200
 Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:172
 Codeception\Codecept->run() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Command\Run.php:184
 Codeception\Command\Run->execute() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:846
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:122
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept:28
```

Command for test coverage: `codecept run functional LoginFormCest --coverage-xml`
Gives this output:

```
FAILURES!
Tests: 5, Assertions: 3, Failures: 5.


  [yii\base\ErrorException]
  Undefined index: quiet


Exception trace:
 () at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\codeception\base\src\Codeception\Coverage\Subscriber\Printer.php:61
 ::call_user_func:{C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:184}() at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:184
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at C:\xampp\htdocs\stoneart-v2\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:46
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Codecept.php:218
 Codeception\Codecept->printResult() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\src\Codeception\Command\Run.php:204
 Codeception\Command\Run->execute() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:846
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:122
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\Users\j-rub\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept:28
```

Codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    memory_limit: 1024M
    colors: false
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'tests/config/test.php'
            cleanup: false
coverage:
    enabled: true
    whitelist:
        include:
            - common/modules/news/*
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Codeception? Please run codeception with `-vvv` flag and provide a full stack trace.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: 2.1.0 is an odd version to use, upgrade at least to the last release of 2.1.* series, but it is even better to upgrade to latest version 2.3.3

Comment: I ll do this and come back if this was the solution.

Comment: Updating to the newest version did the work for me. Although there seems to be a bug displaying the right version of codeception. Thanks annyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the newest version did the work for me. Although there seems to be a bug displaying the right version of codeception. I would recommend to check your composer.json. Thanks.